# Get Selected Option Text of SELECT using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2010

I have dynamically created option where all values in option are coming from share point list .
Now I want to get the text of selected option . I tried few ways but I was not able to get

#### Code for getting data from list

```js
$("#ddlIncrementType").append(
  $("<option></option>")
    .data("incrementLevel", results[increment].IncrementLevel)
    .val(results[increment].Title)
    .html(results[increment].Title)
);
```

#### Code where my option append

```html
<div class="Increment">
    <label for="sel1">Increment Type:</label>
    <select disabled class="form-control" id="ddlIncrementType">
        <option></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I want to get the text of Selected Option 
Suppose in list there are three options

1. Item One
2. Item Two
3. Item Three

I want exactly text 
Anyone who can help ?

I tried it but does't not worked !

```js
var value = $("#ddlIncrementType").find(":selected").val();

var selectedText = $("#mySelect option:selected").html();

var value = $("#ddlIncrementType").find(":selected").text();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use-

```
$(document).on('change', "#ddlIncrementType", function(){
    var value = $(this).text();
    alert(value);
});
```

Also you should not be using `disabled` for your `<select>`

Comment: This will work when I'll change option I want alert when I land on page

Comment: @NoOne so when do you want the value ? soon after page loads ?

Comment: @NoOne I would like to know the solution.

Comment: Actually I was getting the value but I was calling function before

Comment: var incValue = $("#ddlIncrementType").find(':selected').val();

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
$("#ddlIncrementType option:selected").text();
```